# When merging CSS or JS, a new file is generated for each page type

Tags: css, javascript, frontend

We have a lot of small CSS and JS files and enabling merging seems to be a good choice.

Many of the CSS and JS files are used on every page (home page, category page, product detail page).

Whenever we saw that a different merged file is loaded again on each page, even the contained CSS must be overlapping.

How can we avoid this and reuse more data?

Comment: Alex are you including different css and js files on different pages? Do you have a link or any info confirming that this extra compiliation/merging is happening? I saw somehting about it the other day and I'd like to know more. We've had issues getting our JS to compile/merge recently.

Comment: Do not have a public link. But for example on product pages I have some additional `.css` and `.js` files. In a Magento default installation actually the `.css` files are pretty much globally the same, so the merged file has an identical hash. But for `.js` this differs a lot - so there is a newly combined file for product pages and for category pages and so on - always including the full prototype lib.

Comment: I was searching for the "Merge Javascript Files" feature, to help with cache busting. Hopefully this comment updates the search engine and prevents dups.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer:** never enable Magento's JS/CSS merging function. Overall it's worse for performance throughout the lifecycle of a typical checkout than sending each asset individually.

**Long answer:** You should only be serving one CSS file to users. Multiple files block rendering until all CSS is downloaded. Unless you are serving a huge amount of CSS it's advantageous to send it all at once, then the browser has it cached. Using a pre-processor like Sass or LESS can bring this step into your build process instead of letting Magento do it inefficiently.

For JS, ideally you should not be combining these server-side. Client-side script loaders like AMD/RequireJS are better choices and help manage dependencies, which Magento's Layout XML does not. In the real world though Magento drops in scripts at several points in the checkout flow. You're still better off taking the initial page load hit of multiple requests and having separate but cached assets afterwards.

The Fooman Speedster Advanced extension is your best bet for intelligently combining assets without duplication (today).

You are somewhat limited by the Magento 1.x architecture which starts off with a heap of poor practices for frontend performance. It's not realistic to change the course of that ship. Contribute to Magento 2.

Comment: **"Contribute to Magento 2."**

Answer (score 6):

We have been using the [Fooman Speedster Magento Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-speedster.html). It's a wonderful extension that handles the merging of CSS and JS file to increase the performance of your page.

From the page:

> Speed up your store by combining, compressing and caching Javascript
>   and CSS files. Fooman Speedster combines multiple Javascript and CSS
>   files into a single Javascript file and single CSS file, to enable
>   faster page load times.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. I would like to point out my other free Speedster extension (Speedster Advanced) which comes with a theme optimiser to reduce the double ups in the merged Javascript files - Please see my presentation at the Ibiza Developer Conference 2012 here http://www.magento-developers-paradise.com/wp-content/uploads/Ringleff_Fooman-Speedster-Presentation-Magento-format-v1.2.pdf for details.

Comment: I did a lot of testing. It doesn't get rid of all redundancies, but it does get rid of some. And it's not the best minifier, but the redundancy removal compensates for what you could do on your own with a shell script. @KristofatFooman If you could use the system `uglifyjs --compress` and deal with comments better, you could get an additional improvement of about 4% smaller with my code. im using uglifyjs v3 from node.